# Which plugin is contributing Java perspective?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wanted to know which plugin is contributing Java perspective in eclipse?
And does the same plugin contribute the Create new Java project? If not which plugin contributes it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin provides the java perspective

See the plugin.xml inside the plugin:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
  <perspective
        name="%perspectiveName"
        icon="$nl$/icons/full/eview16/jperspective.gif"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPerspectiveFactory"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
     <description>
        %java.perspective.description
     </description>
  </perspective>
```

You can also often use the [**plugin spy**](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/) if you want to know from which plugin a UI component comes.

For example open the "Create a Java Project" dialog and press **Shift + Alt + F1**

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to know which plugin is contributing Java perspective in eclipse?

All the Java related things in Eclipse goes into plugins namely: `org.eclipse.jdt.*`. You can look through it for more details.

> contribute the Create new Java project

The class responsible for creating Java project is `JavaProjectWizard` under `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin.

In-fact you can get information on any Plugin using in-built Eclipse Plugin Spy using Alt + Shift + F1.

Answer (score 1):

Java Perspective is contributed by `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` and it includes the New Java Project. Recently discovering these things has been greatly simplified: for example, if you create an extension for `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` via the `Extensions` tab of the rich editor for plugin.xml, you'll have a *Browse...* button next to the `targetID` text box, where you can search for the perspective by its user-readable name. Similar for many other extension points.